# Getting a reset password requested Flag exception while working with pdf reader

Tags: android, pdf, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am working on app in which i am using the pdf reader app as well for reading a pdf file stored into the sdcard memory.
But when i click on a button it gave me a exception of reset password requested Flag.
But if i use PDF Viewer app for opening my pdf file then code works perfectly.

**Function for Pdf File:**

```
public void ReadMeFAQ(){
try{
File file = new File("sdcard/VSKServices(Modified).pdf");
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
testIntent.setType("application/pdf");

List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.
            MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if(list.size() > 0 && file.isFile()) {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
}
startActivity(testIntent);
}catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

---

**Log Cat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: resetPasswordRequestedFlag     at
com.adobe.reader.PageView.resetPasswordRequestedFlag(Native Method)
com.adobe.reader.PageView.resetPasswordRequestedFlag(Unknown Source)
com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader.dismissPasswdDialogAndResetPasswdAvailable(Unknown Source)
com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader.onResume(Unknown Source)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:957)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.adobe.reader/.AdobeReader
```

Thanks in advance for Any suggestion or help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now it is the version of Adobe reader. First I have used Adobe reader.apk version 10.0.0 which not working with 2.2 or higher bu now I am using adobe.reader_60548.apk version 10.2.1 and it working fine.